# form in php using javascript, ajax, jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have created a form with HTML and process the data via a PHP page and I want to receive/display "*inserted/failed*" notification on same page(***index.html***). I'm using javascript, ajax and jquery. Data is updated in the database but I'm getting result on the ***process.php*** page. I want to insert result notification on ***index.html*** page itself.

index.html

```
<html>
<head><title>Registration form</title></head>
<body>
<form id="myForm" action="process.php" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="username"> <br />
Password: <input type="password" name="pass"> <br />
First name: <input type="text" name="fname"> <br />
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"> <br />

<button id="submit" name="submit">Register</button>
</form>

<div id="ack">Acknowledge</div> 

<script type="text/JavaScript" src="script/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="script/my_script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my_script.js

```
$("#submit").click( function(){


    $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),
            $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
            function(info){
            $("#ack").empty();
            $("#ack").html(info);
            clear();
            });
$("#myForm").submit( function(){
    return false;
    });
});

function clear(){

    $("#myForm:input").each( function()){
        $(this).val("");
    }
}
```

Comment: paste the code of process.php page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#submit").on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post(
            $("#myForm").attr("action"),
            $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
            function(info,status,xhr){
                $("#ack").empty();
                $("#ack").html(info);
                clear();
            }
    );
});

function clear(){
    $("#myForm:input").each(function(){
        $(this).val("");
    });
}
```

PHP page(I'm echoing "success" in the PHP page, so the same content will reflect in the HTML page):

```
<?php echo "success";?>
```

Output:

```
success
```

Comment: You're welcome :) just wondering, why isn't it accepted yet ;)